# MTPro2 and pmatrix

Tags: matrices, mtpro

I am using the `mtpro2` package for math. Recently I changed the `pmatrix` enviroment like the MWE shows, in order to use the `\PARENS` command for the parenthesis of the matrix.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0,BoldFont={Minion Pro Bold}]{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{environ}
\let\pmatrix\relax
\let\endpmatrix\relax
\NewEnviron{pmatrix}{\PARENS{\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}}}

\expandafter\let\csname pmatrix*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endpmatrix*\endcsname\relax
\NewEnviron{pmatrix*}[1][c]{\PARENS{\begin{matrix*}[#1]\BODY\end{matrix*}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

If I place the `pmatrix` enviroment inside `\[  \]` then everything works fine. The `pmatrix` inside the `gather`, `gather*` or any other math enviroment does not compile an gives the following error:

```
Argument of \pmatrix has an extra }. \end{gather}
```

and a bunch of other errors.

Comment: To begin with, using Times for math and Minion for text is dubious.

Comment: `{\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}}` will work. Maybe it's solvable in a different way.

Comment: @egreg I tried it with many different enviroments and it works indeed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is solved by comment.