# Overwrite matrix to work inside align (to use mtpro2 parentheses and braces)

Tags: align, matrices, cases, mtpro

To use large round parentheses and large curly braces provided by the MathTime Pro 2 font, I’m using the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9785/164314) by @BrunoLeFloch to redefine `pmatrix`, `Bmatrix` and `cases`. However, this implementation does not work when the matrices (or cases) are inside the `align` (and friends) environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
% in case you don't have mtpro2, use the following
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
%\providecommand*\PARENS[1]{\left(#1\right)}
%\providecommand*\LEFTRIGHT[3]{\left#1#3\right#2}
\usepackage{environ}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9785/164314
\newcommand{\OverwriteEnviron}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\let\csname env@#1@parse\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\let\csname env@#1@save@env\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\let\csname env@#1@process\endcsname\relax%
  \NewEnviron{#1}%
}
\OverwriteEnviron{pmatrix}{\PARENS{%
  \begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}}}
\OverwriteEnviron{Bmatrix}{\LEFTRIGHT\{\}{%
  \begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}}}
\OverwriteEnviron{cases}{\LEFTRIGHT\lbrace.{\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \begin{array}{@{\,}l@{\quad}l@{}}\BODY\end{array}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Works!}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\begin{Bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{Bmatrix} \quad
\begin{cases}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{cases}
\]

\section{Do not work}
\begin{align*}
%\begin{pmatrix}
%a & b \\
%c & d \\
%\end{pmatrix} \quad
%\begin{Bmatrix}
%a & b \\
%c & d \\
%\end{Bmatrix} \quad
%\begin{cases}
%a & b \\
%c & d \\
%\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: new definitions of matrices and cases]

A very similar question has been [asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348213/164314), but no answers have been provided. I think the problem lies in the nested tabulars where TeX gets confused by the alignment tab `&`. I am also aware of the [“dirty tricks” of `` \ifnum`{=0\fi `` and `` \ifnum`}=0\fi ``](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10371/164314). But I have no clue how to implement these tricks. Any ideas?

Comment: Note you have the same problem if you define a new environment such as `\NewEnviron{xx}{\PARENS{\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}}}`.  Putting the result inside a group inside the align, `{\begin{xx}a&b\end{xx}}`, makes it compilable again.

Comment: By the way, you can simply do `\RenewEnviron{pmatrix}` instead of the tricky code that was written before a new version of `environ` was issued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without `environ`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox{\matrixbox}

\renewenvironment{pmatrix}
 {\setbox\matrixbox=\hbox\bgroup$\begin{matrix}}
 {\end{matrix}$\egroup\PARENS{\copy\matrixbox}}
\renewenvironment{Bmatrix}
 {\setbox\matrixbox=\hbox\bgroup$\begin{matrix}}
 {\end{matrix}$\egroup\LEFTRIGHT\{\}{\copy\matrixbox}}
\renewenvironment{cases}
 {\setbox\matrixbox=\hbox\bgroup$\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \begin{array}{@{\,}l@{\quad}l@{}}}
 {\end{array}$\egroup\LEFTRIGHT\lbrace.{\copy\matrixbox}}

\begin{document}
\section{Works!}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\begin{Bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{Bmatrix} \quad
\begin{cases}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{cases}
\]

\section{Works as well}
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{Bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{Bmatrix} \quad
\begin{cases}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
a & \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix} \\
e & f
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is so much more elegant!!! Thank you for providing this neat trick! I took your technique and came up with my own version of the answer. I was wondering if you’d make some comments on mine (before I accept your answer). :-) I’m going to ask a separate follow-up question if you find no problem in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following code is heavily inspired by [@egreg’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446456/164314). In particular, the technique of box manipulation is used. There are two major improvements:

1. The `\matrix@check` feature of `amsmath` is preserved for `pmatrix` and `cases`.
2. Large curly braces are used for `Bmatrix` and `cases` *if and only if* the package option `curlybraces` is passed to `mtpro2`. For options `morphedbraces` and `straightbraces`, it makes much more sense to use large straight braces.

Additionally, similar patches are applied to `pmatrix*` and `Bmatrix*` from the `mathtools` package (which I did *not* mention in my original question). Finally, as pointed out by [a previous answer by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315010/164314), I have removed `\mskip-\thinmuskip` from the definition of `\LEFTRIGHT`. I think sharing my code would be helpful to others.

Here are my results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% loads `amsmath'
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=0.861,lining]{FiraMono}
\def\bracesshape{curlybraces}% change here to obtain different braces
% curlybraces
% morphedbraces
% straightbraces
\usepackage[lite,\bracesshape]{mtpro2}

% Patches begin
\makeatletter
% Fix weird space
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\LEFTRIGHT}
  {\kern-2\nulldelimiterspace\mskip-\thinmuskip}
  {\kern-2\nulldelimiterspace}
  {}{}
% Two new boxes
\newsavebox{\mtp@matrixbox}
\newsavebox{\mtp@casesbox}
% Round parentheses should always be used by default
% `pmatrix' from `amsmath'
\renewenvironment{pmatrix}{%
  \matrix@check\pmatrix\setbox\mtp@matrixbox=\hbox\bgroup$\env@matrix
}{%
  \endmatrix$\egroup\PARENS{\copy\mtp@matrixbox}%
}
% Curly braces are used only if `curlybraces' is set
% From `mtpro2.sty': \DeclareOption{curlybraces}{\let\mtp@br=c}
\ifx\mtp@br c
  % `Bmatrix' from `amsmath'
  \renewenvironment{Bmatrix}{%
    \setbox\mtp@matrixbox=\hbox\bgroup$\env@matrix
  }{%
    \endmatrix$\egroup\LEFTRIGHT\lbrace\rbrace{\copy\mtp@matrixbox}%
  }
  % `cases' from `amsmath'
  \renewcommand*\env@cases{%
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \setbox\mtp@casesbox=\hbox\bgroup$%
    \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
    \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
  }
  \renewenvironment{cases}{%
    \matrix@check\cases\env@cases
  }{%
    \endarray$\egroup\LEFTRIGHT\lbrace.{\copy\mtp@casesbox}%
  }
\fi
% Now, the matrices from `mathtools'
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\MaybeMHPrecedingSpacesOff
% `pmatrix*' from `mathtools'
\renewenvironment{pmatrix*}[1][c]
  {\setbox\mtp@matrixbox=\hbox\bgroup$\MT_matrix_begin:N #1}
  {\MT_matrix_end:$\egroup\PARENS{\copy\mtp@matrixbox}}
\MH_if_meaning:NN \mtp@br c
  % `Bmatrix*' from `mathtools'
  \renewenvironment{Bmatrix*}[1][c]
    {\setbox\mtp@matrixbox=\hbox\bgroup$\MT_matrix_begin:N #1}
    {\MT_matrix_end:$\egroup\LEFTRIGHT\lbrace\rbrace{\copy\mtp@matrixbox}}
\MH_fi:
\MHPrecedingSpacesOn
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother
% Patches end

\newcommand*\showopendelimitersizes[1]{%
  #1\bigl#1\Bigl#1\biggl#1\Biggl#1}

\begin{document}

\section*{Matrices and cases in \texttt{align} now work!}
Matrices from \verb|amsmath| and \verb|mathtools| work;
\verb|cases| from \verb|amsmath| works.
\subsection*{Package \texttt{mtpro2} options: \texttt{lite,\bracesshape}}
\begin{align*}
\showopendelimitersizes{(}
\begin{pmatrix}
-a &  b \\
 c & -d \\
-a &  b \\
 c & -d \\
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\showopendelimitersizes{\lbrace}
\begin{Bmatrix*}[r]
-a &  b \\
 c & -d \\
-a &  b \\
 c & -d \\
\end{Bmatrix*} \quad
\begin{cases}
-a &  b \\
 c & -d \\
-a &  b \\
 c & -d \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: matrices and cases with mtpro2]