# Overwrite dcases* to work inside align (to use mtpro2 braces)

Tags: align, conditionals, cases, mathtools, mtpro

This is a direct follow-up question from my previous one: [Overwrite `matrix` to work inside `align` (to use `mtpro2` parentheses and braces)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446450/164314). Although this question is self-contained, I encourage anyone who is interested to read that post first.

My goal is to overwrite the `mathtools` package’s `dcases*` and friends, so that large curly braces from the MathTime Pro 2 font can be used *automatically*. Note that although the “complete” version of MTPro2 is non-free, the “lite” version (which contains large curly braces) *is* [freely available](https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html).

Note that `pmatrix`, `Bmatrix` and `cases` from `amsmath`; and `pmatrix*` and `Bmatrix*` from `mathtools` were taken care of in [my own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446518/164314), which was based on [@egreg’s excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446456/164314) with two noticeable improvements.

## Requirements

For `dcases*` and friends, there is only one requirement:

- Use large curly braces if package option `curlybraces` is passed to `mtpro2`. Otherwise, with option `morphedbraces` or `straightbraces`, use large *straight* braces.

## Useful information

Large curly braces are accessed via the `mtpro2` command

```
\LEFTRIGHT<left delimiter><right delimiter>{<contents>}% `mtpro2' exclusive
```

while large straight braces can be obtained simply by

```
\left<left delimiter> <contents> \right<right delimiter>
```

Furthermore, the 3 brace-shape package options are declared as

```
% From `mtpro2.sty'
\DeclareOption{curlybraces}{\let\mtp@br=c}
\DeclareOption{morphedbraces}{\let\mtp@br=m}
\DeclareOption{straightbraces}{\let\mtp@br=s}
```

## My attempt

The ideas are the same as in [@egreg’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446456/164314) and [my own](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446518/164314): 1) Store the contents of the cases in a box `\mtp@casesbox`. 2) Print the box with `\LEFTRIGHT` (when `curlybraces` is set).

However, `mathtools` creates `dcases*` and friends differently from how `amsmath` redefines `cases`. So, I used two new building macros `\MTP_MT_start_cases:nnn` and `\MTP_MH_end_cases:`, with two new commands `\mtp@newcases` and `\mtp@renewcases`. As the names suggest, the two commands are made internal *on purpose*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% loads `amsmath'
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=0.861,lining]{FiraMono}
\def\bracesshape{curlybraces}% change here to obtain different braces
% curlybraces
% morphedbraces
% straightbraces
\usepackage[lite,\bracesshape]{mtpro2}

% Patches begin
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\mtp@casesbox}
% Activate `mathtools' syntax
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
% Curly braces are used only if `curlybraces' is set
% From `mtpro2.sty': \DeclareOption{curlybraces}{\let\mtp@br=c}
\MH_if_meaning:NN \mtp@br c
  \def\MTP_MT_start_cases:nnn #1#2#3{ % #1=sep,#2=lpreamble,#3=rpreamble
   \RIfM@\else
     \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}
   \fi
   \MH_group_align_safe_begin:
   \setbox\mtp@casesbox=\hbox\bgroup$% <- put contents in `\mtp@casesbox'
   \vcenter \bgroup
       \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
       \let  \math@cr@@\AMS@math@cr@@
       \spread@equation
       \ialign\bgroup
         \strut@#2 &#1\strut@
         #3
         \crcr
  }
  \def\MTP_MH_end_cases:{\crcr\egroup
   \restorecolumn@
   \egroup
   $\egroup% <- close the `\hbox'
   \MH_group_align_safe_end:
  }
  \newcommand*\mtp@newcases[6]{% #1=name, #2=sep, #3=lpreamble, #4=rpreamble, #5=left, #6=right
   \newenvironment{#1}
     {\MTP_MT_start_cases:nnn {#2}{#3}{#4}}
     {\MTP_MH_end_cases:\LEFTRIGHT#5#6{\copy\mtp@casesbox}}
  }
  \newcommand*\mtp@renewcases[6]{
   \renewenvironment{#1}
     {\MTP_MT_start_cases:nnn {#2}{#3}{#4}}
     {\MTP_MH_end_cases:\LEFTRIGHT#5#6{\copy\mtp@casesbox}}
  }
  \mtp@renewcases{dcases}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
  \mtp@renewcases{dcases*}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
  \mtp@renewcases{rcases}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th{##}$\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
  \mtp@renewcases{rcases*}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
  \mtp@renewcases{drcases}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
  \mtp@renewcases{drcases*}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
  \mtp@renewcases{cases*}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
\MH_fi:
% Deactivate `mathtools' syntax
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother
% Patches end

\newcommand*\showopendelimitersizes[1]{%
  #1\bigl#1\Bigl#1\biggl#1\Biggl#1}

\begin{document}

\section*{\texttt{dcases*} in \texttt{align} work?}
\verb|dcases*| and friends from \verb|mathtools| work,
iff \verb|curlybraces| is set.
\subsection*{Package \texttt{mtpro2} options: \texttt{lite,\bracesshape}}
\begin{align*}
\showopendelimitersizes{\lbrace}
\begin{dcases*}
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x    & Nothing to see here \\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} & Otherwise
\end{dcases*}
\end{align*}
With \verb|morphedbraces| or \verb|straightbraces|,
errors appear.

\end{document}
```

[image: curly braces work]

## Problems

My implementation works *if and only if* the package option `curlybraces` is used. If the package option `morphedbraces` or `straightbraces` is used, the following errors appear:

```
% Hit <compile>
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{document} allowed only in math mode.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21      \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}

% Hit <return>
! Only one # is allowed per tab.
l.31          #
               3

% Hit <return>
! Extra \fi.
l.64 \MH_fi:

% Hit <return>
! Undefined control sequence.
\dcases* ->\MTP_MT_start_cases:nnn 
                                   {\quad }{$\m@th \displaystyle {##}$\hfil ...
l.85 \end{align*}

...
```

- **Major question**: Why do these errors appear? **Added**: My educated guess: The errors are likely to arise from how TeX deals with conditionals.
- **Minor question**: Did I insert `\setbox\mtp@casesbox=\hbox\bgroup$` and `$\egroup` to the correct spots? I ask this, because in the definition of the original `\newcases` and `\renewcases`, `\left#4` comes *after* `\MH_group_align_safe_begin:` but `\right#6` also comes *after* `\MH_group_align_safe_end:`?! This is rather surprising: I thought `\right#6` should come *before* `\MH_group_align_safe_end:`.

Alternative solutions are more than welcome (to this question as well as to [my previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446450/164314))!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\RIfM@` expands to a conditional, but is not a conditional itself from TeX's perspective. So the `\fi` ending the conditional block is considered the `\fi` ending the `\MH_if_meaning:NN` block, iff TeX's tries to skip this block and therefore does not expand it. This can be fixed by moving the conditional code into a macro argument which is either evaluated or gobbled depending on the conditional:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% loads `amsmath'
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=0.861,lining]{FiraMono}
\def\bracesshape{straightbraces}% change here to obtain different braces
% curlybraces
% morphedbraces
% straightbraces
\usepackage[lite,\bracesshape]{mtpro2}

% Patches begin
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\mtp@casesbox}
% Activate `mathtools' syntax
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
% Curly braces are used only if `curlybraces' is set
% From `mtpro2.sty': \DeclareOption{curlybraces}{\let\mtp@br=c}
\MH_if_meaning:NN \mtp@br c
  \expandafter\@firstofone
\MH_else:
  \expandafter\@gobble
\MH_fi:{
  \def\MTP_MT_start_cases:nnn #1#2#3{ % #1=sep,#2=lpreamble,#3=rpreamble
   \RIfM@\else
     \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}
   \fi
   \MH_group_align_safe_begin:
   \setbox\mtp@casesbox=\hbox\bgroup$% <- put contents in `\mtp@casesbox'
   \vcenter \bgroup
       \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
       \let  \math@cr@@\AMS@math@cr@@
       \spread@equation
       \ialign\bgroup
         \strut@#2 &#1\strut@
         #3
         \crcr
  }
  \def\MTP_MH_end_cases:{\crcr\egroup
   \restorecolumn@
   \egroup
   $\egroup% <- close the `\hbox'
   \MH_group_align_safe_end:
  }
  \newcommand*\mtp@newcases[6]{% #1=name, #2=sep, #3=lpreamble, #4=rpreamble, #5=left, #6=right
   \newenvironment{#1}
     {\MTP_MT_start_cases:nnn {#2}{#3}{#4}}
     {\MTP_MH_end_cases:\LEFTRIGHT#5#6{\copy\mtp@casesbox}}
  }
  \newcommand*\mtp@renewcases[6]{
   \renewenvironment{#1}
     {\MTP_MT_start_cases:nnn {#2}{#3}{#4}}
     {\MTP_MH_end_cases:\LEFTRIGHT#5#6{\copy\mtp@casesbox}}
  }
  \mtp@renewcases{dcases}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
  \mtp@renewcases{dcases*}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
  \mtp@renewcases{rcases}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th{##}$\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
  \mtp@renewcases{rcases*}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
  \mtp@renewcases{drcases}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
  \mtp@renewcases{drcases*}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{.}{\rbrace}
  \mtp@renewcases{cases*}{\quad}{%
    $\m@th{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
}
% Deactivate `mathtools' syntax
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother
% Patches end

\newcommand*\showopendelimitersizes[1]{%
  #1\bigl#1\Bigl#1\biggl#1\Biggl#1}

\begin{document}

\section*{\texttt{dcases*} in \texttt{align} work?}
\verb|dcases*| and friends from \verb|mathtools| work,
iff \verb|curlybraces| is set.
\subsection*{Package \texttt{mtpro2} options: \texttt{lite,\bracesshape}}
\begin{align*}
\showopendelimitersizes{\lbrace}
\begin{dcases*}
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x    & Nothing to see here \\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} & Otherwise
\end{dcases*}
\end{align*}
With \verb|morphedbraces| or \verb|straightbraces|,
errors appear.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I have found an alternative as well: Simply replace `\RIfM@` with its expanded form `\relax\ifmmode` as defined in [`amsgen.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsgen.dtx): `\def\RIfM@{\relax\ifmmode}`. But, of course, your solution requires less digging.