# Curly braces using mtpro2[lite]: fix correct alignment

Tags: align, braces, cases, mtpro

I am trying to find a solution, but actually I have failed, to use curly bracket (using `\ccases`) for the system symbol of three equations (or more), as for this example. If I adding the `&` I have much space,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\ccases{
x&=R\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
y&=R\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
z&=R\cos\theta}
\]
\end{document}
```

While if I remove the symbol `&` I lose the vertical alignment of the sign `=`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\ccases{
x=R\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
y=R\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
z=R\cos\theta}
\]
\end{document}
```

*How can I have the correct vertical alignment with the three `=` symbols  without have additional spaces?*

**ADDENDUM:** Here there is an image which compares the classic brace with the elegant curvy brace:

[image]

First guide [mtpro2](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/guide2.pdf) page 12 and second guide [mtpro2-2008/1/23](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/mtpro2.pdf) and possible related:

1. [Overwrite dcases* to work inside align (to use mtpro2 braces)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446631/overwrite-dcases-to-work-inside-align-to-use-mtpro2-braces?rq=1)
2. [Overwrite matrix to work inside align (to use mtpro2 parentheses and braces)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446450/overwrite-matrix-to-work-inside-align-to-use-mtpro2-parentheses-and-braces/446456#446456)

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the command `\ccases` come from?

Comment: @Bernard Aesthetically creates the most elegant system symbol compared to the default design.

Comment: But where did you find it? Does it come with `mtpro2lite`?

Comment: @Bernard - Indeed, it's the ``mtpro2` package which defines the `\ccases`(presumably shorthand for "curly cases") command..

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the info! Apparently, it's probably based on `eqnarray` (conjectured from the syntax for alignment and the spacing problem…)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the scope of `\ccases{...}`, the `&` symbol performs the same function as it does inside the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package, i.e., it creates a certain amount of horizontal separation (as well as vertical alignment). However, that's not what you want here, is it?

To get the desired spacing around the `=` symbols, I recommend that you encase the three equations in an `aligned` environment, regardless of whether you use the `\ccases` macro or the `cases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\ccases{
  \begin{aligned}
    x &= R\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
    y &= R\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
    z &= R\cos\theta
  \end{aligned}
}
\quad\text{vs.}\qquad
\begin{cases}
  \begin{aligned}
    x &= R\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
    y &= R\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
    z &= R\cos\theta
  \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Always my profound thanks for your most precious help. In the two guides that I have attached I had found nothing. Grazieeeeeeee

Comment: @Sebastiano - You're most welcome!

Comment: Is it really very nice!