# Curly bracket for subequation enviroment using the mtpro2 v. lite

Tags: brackets, cases, subequations, mtpro, empheq

Remembering the very nice answer given by the user @Mico, [Curly braces using mtpro2[lite]: fix correct alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505851/curly-braces-using-mtpro2lite-fix-correct-alignment), it has been used into an equation the enviroment

```
\ccases{\begin{aligned}.....\end{aligned}}
```

(here the complete code)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\ccases{
  \begin{aligned}
    x &= R\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
    y &= R\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
    z &= R\cos\theta
  \end{aligned}
}
\quad\text{vs.}\qquad
\begin{cases}
  \begin{aligned}
    x &= R\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
    y &= R\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
    z &= R\cos\theta
  \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

to have a very nice curly bracket, as the below image.

[image]

But using the enviroment `subequation` into this MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathtools,newtxtext}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\ccases{\begin{aligned}
A &= B\\
C &= D\\
F &= G \\
H &= I
\end{aligned}
}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

I have not obtained the curly brace symbol, because I have this warning:

> Undefined control sequence.
>   l.7 \cccases
>               {\begin{aligned}

If I use this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathtools,newtxtext}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
A  &= C\\
F &= 0 \\
Ah &= ty\\
qw &= oo
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

the code compile correctly but I have not the curly bracket but the classic bracket of a sisteme:

[image]

What can be the solution(s) for my problem?

Comment: Aren't you missing the obvious? Subequations does not enter math mode, ccaces is presumably a math macro.

Comment: BTW empheqlbrace is made via `\DeclareLeftDelimiter{\lbrace}` and lbrace is just the normal `\{`. Can't you just make an appropriate mtpro lbrace.

Comment: `\begin{subequations}` does *not* start math mode. The error is, indeed, `! Missing $ inserted.` (not `\cccases` undefined, which was probably due to a typo).

Comment: @daleif Thank you very much for two your suggestions that I not have known.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for your indications. I have understood the problem.